# Python Pandas / Numpy indexing faster than np.where between 2 arrays

Tags: python

I have 2 pandas datasets which have 'RF' field in common.  The `optionsdata` variable is ~60K, which map to at most the `histdata` fields of 5K.  Using `np.where` is incredibly slow:

```
for j in range(0,len(optionsdata)):
    optionsmap[j] = np.where(histdata.ix['RF'].str.match(optionsdata.RF[j]))[0][0]
```

Is there a much faster way to do this?  All I need is the row # for each value in `optionsdata` which corresponds to the RF row in `histdata`.

I should note the field compared is a string such as 'NYMEX_01_MAR_2016'

Comment: I think you may be misunderstanding what np.where(x) is meant for. The full signature version where(condition,x,y) returns an array the same shape as its inputs, with elements  containing either x[i] if c[i] is true or y[i] otherwise. The short version contains an array containing *every* index where condition is nonzero. You're basically evaluating a string match (slow) for your whole array in order to assign each element.

Comment: As why I am asking for help here - do you have a better method to propose?  I'd like to hear.

Comment: I think the lazy answer is probably to generate a dictionary with keys taken from the histdata and values of the row numbers. Not that I'm saying this is the best way mind you, but it still ought to be faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not 100% clear to me what your dataframes look like, but I believe you could do this with the [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#database-style-dataframe-joining-merging) function of pandas. Your code would be

```
optionsmap = pandas.merge(optionsdata,histdata,on="RF",how="left")
```

Comment: That is a quite incredible task there in 1 line of code! However, I'm not trying to merge the 2 dataframes together, just get the row # where RF matches - due to memory constraints, I'd rather keep the 2 dataframes separate.  Building on your suggestion @LKlevin I came up with the solution.  The whole thing takes probably 1/10 of a second now.  Many thanks!


`RFmap = pd.DataFrame(histdata.RF)`

`RFmap.insert(0,'RFmap',np.arange(0,len(RFmap)))`

`optionsdata = pd.merge(optionsdata, RFmap, on="RF", how="left")`

Comment: FYI although I asked the question with `optionsmap`, the solution posted instead makes the `optionsdata.RFrow` the row index to `histdata`.  This should be a built in pandas function...